# How to get hand cursor when using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Hi i have a div like this

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in array" ></div>
```

I  want mouse pointer to change into hand type curson on hover of this.
Is there any simple way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

just with css:

```
<div class="row" style="cursor:pointer;" ng-repeat="item in array" ></div>
```

You could also add this to you'r `.row` css class

```
.row {
    cursor: pointer;
    ...
}
```

Comment: and it is not working when the repeat is in ng-dialog . any reason @Rocky

Comment: @VaraVarun is there something generated in the div? then you should add the cursor:pointer; to there

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS file, add:

```
.row {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in array" >
   <a style="cursor:pointer">{{item.yourData}}</a>
</div>
```